# How do we recognize hardware used in accelerator physics

Tags: soft-question, accelerator-physics

When I see a new accelerator in real life or on a picture, I always find it interesting to see how many thing I can recognize. In that way, I can also get a small first idea of how the accelerator is working.
Here is a picture, I have taken of LEIR at CERN[image: LEIR]

Help me to be able to recognize even more stuff, than I can now(I will post a few answers myself)

Suggested answer form:

- **Title**
- **Images**
- **One line description**
- **Link**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quadrupole magnet**
[image: Quadrupole magnet]
Quadrupole magnets are mostly used for beam focusing.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_magnet

Answer (score 1):

**Sextupole magnet**
[image: Sextupole magnets]
Sextupole magnets are mainly used to correct for [chromaticity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromaticity).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sextupole_magnet

Answer (score 1):

**Ion pump**
[image: Ion pumps]

Ion pumps are used to pump away rest gas in beam tubes at very low pressure.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion_pump_(physics)

Answer (score 1):

**Electron cooler**
[image: Electron cooler]

Electron coolers are used to cool beams of heavier particles.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_cooling

Answer (score 1):

**Dipole magnet**
[image: Dipole magnet]

Look at the brown blocks at the lower left of the picture in the question. Dipole magnets are used for bending the trajectory of the particles.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_magnet